# Javascript (Adobe Acrobat XI) populate 2nd page form from inputted answers from 1st page in form

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe, acrobat

I want to start by saying I'm NOT fluent in javascript, however, I am learning and can read the code and comprehend it.  I make professional fillable PDF forms, using javascript to perform actions and calculations, but I've never had to do this before.  My request is specifically for Adobe Acrobat XI Pro javascript.

I have an order form I created.  I've added a button (called 'Create Invoice')on the page to adds a page (using:var a = this.getTemplate("Invoice");
a.spawn();) after the order form that presents the information that was entered or calculated from the first page.  I ONLY want to show fields on the invoice that were selected on the first page.

Here's a screen shot [link] of a portion of the Order Form (pg 1):
[IMG]http://i61.tinypic.com/iqk3sm.jpg[/IMG]
(I can't post images until 10 reputation)

So on the Invoice (pg 2) I want ONLY the (2) items chosen above to show, in immediate succession:
[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/o59jt3.jpg[/IMG]
(I can't post images until 10 reputation)

The DESCRIPTION column will ideally concatenate the "Saddle Name" + "Color". The rest of the columns should be obvious (fill in with the associated fields for each item ordered).

So, what should the code look like for this?  And should the Javascript be put onto a field or Document Javascripts?

(This is my first stackoverflow post, I apologize if I did anything wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

So, the first page is a static page where the user fills the table as such. And the second page should have a well-ordered list of the ordered items.

The first page should be pretty straightforward, with hierarchical field naming (but it may be a good idea to have the line number not at the end (as Acrobat does when you multiply the selected fields), but in the middle of the file name(s). This would then allow you to handle lines in a much simpler way. The same principle would apply for page 2.

After spawning the second page, you loop through the rows on page 1, and if the number of items is not equal to its default, fill the table on page 2.

In order to be able to delete an order again, it might be useful to completely reset the table on page 2, and fill it up from new; here smart field naming will gain you a lot of time.

You would add that code (including calculation of totals etc.) in the Calculate event of a hidden field which is only used as a carrier for all calculations, including building totals etc.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean in your 2nd paragraph?  (field renaming, line numbers?)

I can't really visualize what you're trying to example.  

Would I need to set an array for each column? or each row? to achieve my desired results?

Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Sorry for having been a bit cryptic… If you multiply selected fields in Acrobat, it will add an ordinal number at the end, such as starting from "myField" to "myField.0", "myField.1", etc.. It has proven more practical, however, to bring the ordinal number into the middle of the field name. Example: the "pattern field names" for the table are "order.numItems", "order.itemName", "order.unitPrice" and "order.itemTotal". Now, when you put them into the actual table, you would set the names to "order.0.itemName", "order.1.itemName", "order.2.itemName", "order.0.unitPrice" and so on (continued…)

Comment: … so that the ordinal number stands for the row in the column. Calculations are simpler in this scenario, and with this.getField("order.2").display = display.hidden, you can hide a whole row with one single command.